# Using base class function when no mock functionality provided [Moq]

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I'm having trouble figuring out how to make my `Moq` unit tests use an already-implemented function if I don't provide a mocked functionality. I have a `IService` interface which is implemented by both `ServiceA` and `ServiceB` and a `Manager.cs` which makes use of an `IService`:

`IService.cs` :

```
public interface IService{
  void Start();
  void Stop();
  void Fail();
  HttpClient CreateHttpClient(string target);
}
```

`ServiceA.cs`:

```
public class ServiceA : IService {  
    public ServiceA(){ }

    public void Start(){ 
        CreateHttpClient(); // this is ultimately what I need to mock
    }
    public void Stop(){ /* stuff */ }
    public void Fail(){ /* stuff */ }
    // I want to create a mocked response for CreateHttpClient() 
    // in my unit test
    public void CreateHttpClient(string target ){
        return new HttpClient();
    }
}
```

`ServiceB.cs`:

```
public class ServiceB: IService {   
    public ServiceB(){ }

    public void Start(){ /* slightly different stuff */ }
    public void Stop(){ /* slightly different stuff */ }
    public void Fail(){ /* slightly different stuff */ }
    public void CreateHttpClient(string target ){
        // slightly different httpclient implementation 
        return new HttpClient();
    }
}
```

`Manager.cs`:

```
public class Manager {
    private readonly IService _service;
    
    public Manager(IService service){
        _service = service;
    }
    
    public void Start(){
        _service.Start(); // I want this to call ServiceA.Start() or ServiceB.Start()
                          // if no mocked implementation provided 
    }
    
}
```

`MyUnitTests.cs`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void MyUnitTest{
    var mock = new Mock<IService>();
    mock.Setup(m => m.CreateHttpClient(null)).Returns(new HttpClient()));

    var manager = new Manager(mock.Object);
    manager.Start();
    

}
```

I've tried experimenting with `mock.CallBase = true` but haven't been successful. I suspect I will have to change this line `var mockedClass = new Mock<IService>();` to something that specifies which service (`ServiceA` or `ServiceB`) but I'm not sure how those interfaces would have to look like.

Comment: If you use a mock, you are responsible to set up the configuration of `Start` method. If you don't want to set up the mock, then directly inject ServiceA or ServiceB into the Manager class. BTW, I'm confused about why do you need both mock and service classes here. can explain your problem more in detail?

Comment: @codeninja.sj I added a line to MyUnitTest and a couple of comments to `ServiceA.cs`. I am trying to mock CreateHttpClient which is called from `Start()`

Comment: If you want to mock HttpClient, then you should inject it inside the constructor first. Take a look at this blog, it will help you: https://dev.to/gautemeekolsen/how-to-test-httpclient-with-moq-in-c-2ldp